# EasyMock and JNA - Mock Generic Return Type

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, powermock, easymock

I am trying to mock the following JNA call using EasyMock

```
convInterface = (ConvInterface)  Native.loadLibrary(libraryLocation,ConvInterface.class);
```

Using this test method

```
@Test
public void testLib() {
    Capture<Class<?>> myClassCapture  = EasyMock.newCapture();
    PowerMock.mockStatic(Native.class);

    EasyMock.expect(Native.loadLibrary(EasyMock.isA(String.class), EasyMock.capture(myClassCapture))).andReturn(mockConvInterface);
    PowerMock.replay(Native.class);

    ConvServiceImpl myLib = new ConvServiceImpl();
    myLib.instantiateConvLibrary();

    PowerMock.verify(Native.class);
}
```

I am getting the following error using version 4.3.0 of the JNA library

```
The method andReturn(capture#1-of ?) in the type IExpectationSetters<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (ConvInterface)
```

The same code is fine with version 4.2.0 of the JNA library

Here are the method signatures for the method I am trying to mock

Version 4.2.0

```
public static Object loadLibrary(String name, Class interfaceClass) {
```

Version 4.3

```
public static <T> T loadLibrary(String name, Class<T> interfaceClass) {
```

How do I go about mocking the return of a generic return type using EasyMock?

Thanks
Damien

Comment: May I ask why you're even using a `Capture` for the `Class` parameter of `loadLibrary` in the first place? I don't see why it should be needed or useful.

Comment: I had saw on a stackoverflow previously to use a Capture for Class - would you recommend another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the simplest answer is: don't use `Capture` for this test, there is no need.

The question uses PowerMock + EasyMock, but since I don't have these libraries on hand, here is a much shorter version of the test (verified to work), using JMockit:

```
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import mockit.*;
import com.sun.jna.*;

public final class JNATest {
    public interface ConvInterface extends Library {}

    public static class ConvServiceImpl {
        final String libraryLocation = "whatever";
        ConvInterface convInterface;

        public void instantiateConvLibrary() {
            convInterface = Native.loadLibrary(libraryLocation, ConvInterface.class);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testLib(
        @Mocked Native mockNative, @Mocked ConvInterface mockConvInterface
    ) {
        ConvServiceImpl myLib = new ConvServiceImpl();
        myLib.instantiateConvLibrary();

        assertSame(mockConvInterface, myLib.convInterface);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using Capture as I want to mock an instance of a Class<T>

Comment: What do you mean? `Capture` is meant for capturing arguments of complex values, so that a test can perform additional assertions (eg, using `assertEquals(x, capturedInstance.getSomething())`.

Comment: I have seen folks use Capture to mock instances of Class<T> in the past. Is there a better way?

Comment: `Capture` doesn't "mock" anything; all it does is to "capture" a parameter value passed in a call to a mocked method, at the time this call occurs from the code under test, and then makes this value available to the test when it later calls a "get" method on the `Capture` object. In the particular case of a `Class` value, it doesn't really make sense to use `Capture`; the test would instead use an equality/same argument matcher.

Answer (score 3):

The problem comes from your typing of `Capture<Class<?>>`. This wildcard means you want to capture `something`. Let's call this something `capture#1`. So `loadLibrary` is getting a class of `capture#1` in parameter and to return a `capture#1` instance. So `andReturn` expects a `capture#1` in parameter.

But you are passing a `ConvInterface` which isn't (obviously) a `capture#1`.

The solution is easy. Just do `Capture<Class<ConvInterface>> myClassCapture  = EasyMock.newCapture();` since this is what you expect `loadLibrary` to get.

Comment: I am trying to use PowerMock to mock this call - that is evident in the test method

Comment: Shame on me... Read too quickly. Let me get back to you with an accurate answer...